# Есть ли простой способ узнать в каком парметре sql процедуры вызываемой кодом происходит исключение?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть вот такой типичный код:

```
public int Execute( Dictionary<string, string> transaction, string procedure )
{
    SqlCommand createAuctionCommand = new SqlCommand()
    {
        CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        CommandText = procedure,
        Connection = sqlConnection
    };
    foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in transaction )
    {
        createAuctionCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( pair.Key, pair.Value );
    }

    return createAuctionCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Проблема в том что когда один из сервисов посылает свои данные в эту процедуру то база выдает эксепшн в котором сказано что невозможно привести тип nvarchar к number хотя у меня процедура нигде не принимает number, только строки.

Вопрос в том где можно посмотреть используя SQL Server Managament Studio
 в каком месте происходит попытка присваивания строки к числу?

Comment: Все верно, нигде не принимает, вот только происходит неявное приведение. На вашем месте я бы взял код процедуры, обьявил бы входные переменные и перебирал бы предполагаемые значения + избавился бы от неявного приведения.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, я разобрался. Таблица, куда пишу -  типизированная другими типами и там происходит неявное приведение. Решил перед оправкой в базу все параметры проверять. =)